# Match Polish characters in PHP with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match

I am trying to do some server side validation in PHP. I tried hard but I found still no solution. I am trying to allow only Polish characters in the input.

For this I have used:

```
preg_match('/^[\x{0104}-\x{017c}]*$/u',$titles)
```

This doesn't work however.

Anyone has any idea how to write it properly?

Comment: Please can you provide an example of a string you are testing against?

Comment: Any polish letter like Ąąćś etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match Polish letters only, you just need a character class:

```
[a-pr-uwy-zA-PR-UWY-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]
```

Use as

```
preg_match('/^[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]*$/iu',$titles)
```

Note that there is no `Q`, `V` and `X` in [Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_language), but since they can be met in some words (`taxi`), you may want to allow these letters as well. Then, use `'/^[A-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]*$/iu'` regex.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5oRW3A)

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]*$/iu', "spółka")) {
    echo "The whole string contains only Polish letters";
}
```

Comment: I tried   preg_match('/^[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]*$/iu',$titles) It returns false when I try it with Ą letter. Did you try if what you've written works actually?

Comment: No offence. I did htmlentities on $titles. That was the problem. Works now. Thx.